# Using AJAX Toolkit in Site.com pages

Tags: site.com, ajax-toolkit

This may sound a bit strange, but I'm wondering if anyone has tried to use the AJAX Toolkit from within an authorized Site.com page?  The reason I want to do this is to be able to identify the logged in user, and customize what the user sees on the page.  I know this can be done with Force.com sites, but am looking for a way to do this in Site.com

Thx,
Hamayoun

Comment: I should also add that we are trying to use Site.com pages within an SFDC Community.

Comment: I am also looking for the same.. When I tries to call SOAP API from ajax call in site.com cross domain issue is coming.. I want to know how it is possible to connect site.com pages and APIs.